# Problems upgrading openssl to fix heartbleed - please advise

Tags: apt, openssl

I'm trying to upgrade openssl but hit the following issue - please could you offer some advice on what is wrong here ?

```
# sudo apt-get install openssl libssl1.0.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try `sudo apt-get -f install` with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've not tried tried the apt-get -f install option yet

I followed up as per smurfs suggestion but only got the following :-

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-33 linux-headers-3.2.0-40 linux-headers-3.2.0-37 linux-headers-3.2.0-38
  linux-headers-3.2.0-39 linux-headers-3.2.0-45 linux-image-3.2.0-45-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic
  linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic
  linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-33-generic linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-server linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic linux-image-server linux-server
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.2.0 linux-source-3.2.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
3 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 180 not upgraded.
38 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 150 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up base-files (6.5ubuntu6.7) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue.net ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/lsb-release ...
E: Error: BrokenCount > 0run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 255
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
(Reading database ... 343095 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic_3.2.0-61.92_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
Setting up libdrm2 (2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) ...
Setting up libpciaccess0 (0.12.902-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libdrm-intel1 (2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-nouveau1a (2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-radeon1 (2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-0 (2.32.4-0ubuntu1) ...
No schema files found: doing nothing.
Setting up libnih1 (1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1) ...
Setting up libnih-dbus1 (1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1) ...
Setting up libudev0 (175-0ubuntu9.5) ...
Setting up libplymouth2 (0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools-bin (0.99ubuntu13.5) ...
Setting up busybox-initramfs (1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up iproute (20111117-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.5) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev (3.2.0-53.81) ...
Setting up libc6-dev (2.15-0ubuntu10.5) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.15-0ubuntu10.5) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.79.12) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-53 (3.2.0-53.81) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-53-generic (3.2.0-53.81) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-60 (3.2.0-60.91) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-60-generic (3.2.0-60.91) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-61 (3.2.0-61.92) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-61-generic (3.2.0-61.92) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Setting up linux-headers-server (3.2.0.53.63) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.53.63); however:
  Package linux-image-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Setting up tzdata-java (2014a-0ubuntu0.12.04) ...
Setting up libdevmapper1.02.1 (2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.4) ...
Setting up ifupdown (0.7~beta2ubuntu11) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu13.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up upstart (1.5-0ubuntu7.2) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic (3.2.0-61.92) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.2.0-61-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-61-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-61-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-61-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
Setting up procps (1:3.2.8-11ubuntu6.3) ...
procps stop/waiting
Setting up udev (175-0ubuntu9.5) ...
udev stop/waiting
udev start/running, process 9106
Removing 'diversion of /sbin/udevadm to /sbin/udevadm.upgrade by fake-udev'
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up mountall (2.36.4) ...
Setting up plymouth (0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up dmsetup (2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic


Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-server
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any further ideas here ?

Comment: Solve the dep issue first by running that suggested command

Comment: A standard update of **Ubuntu** fixes 'Heartbleed' vulnerability for OpenSSL (package). *What else are you trying to achieve?*

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what you mean by standard update ?

Answer (score 0):

You had a previous run apt-get interrupted and the package database is in inconsistent state. "apt-get -f install" will fix that and will finish whatever it was doing when it was interrupted. Then you will be able to install other packages, including openssl.

Comment: Sadly that didn't fix the issue :-